# index.jsp in Jetty failing to redirect when dirAllowed=false

Tags: java, redirect, jetty, directory-listing

I was tasked with correcting a listable directories vulnerability in a Java web project running on Jetty. I did this by adding the following to the project's frontend jetty config XML file as a child of the <Call name="addWebApplication"> tag:

```
<Call name="addHandler">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.mortbay.http.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="dirAllowed">false</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

This worked, but had an odd side-effect of partially disabling the redirect from the project's base URL, i.e. entering www..com should redirect to www..com/setupPublicSolicitationSearch.do, but instead it just outputs the contents of index.jsp to the browser; entering www..com/random_junk still redirects to the .do page correctly. The following is the contents of index.jsp:

<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic" %>

<logic:forward name="redirectDefault" />

SysAdmin have confirmed that Apache is forwarding the request to Jetty correctly, and it's definitely the above XML change that caused the problem; deleting that bit of XML allows the project to redirect as expected again.

Comment: Was the problem fixed glehmann? Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.